# Stop wordpress from removing HTML attributes

Tags: tags, html, customization

I try to insert a post with `html tag` with `class` attribute, like this: `<dl class="dl-horizontal">`, but after saving the post, WP removes an attribute.
How can I fix it?
The only way I've found, is to make a `shortcode`:

```
add_shortcode('attr', 'html_attr');
function html_attr( $atts, $content = null ){
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'tag' =>"",
    'attr'=>""
  ), $atts ) );   
  return "<" .  $tag . " " . $attr . " >";
}
```

But I don't think that it's a right way...

Comment: I can't duplicate this issue. The `class` attribute is not removed when I try it. Maybe you have a plugin conflict or your theme is doing something odd.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, I think that it deppends on wich tag we are talking about. I also see that in `span` and `div` tag I can insert `class` and WP does not remove it. But in `dl` tag WP removes attributes.

Comment: I thought about that and I tried it with the `<dl>` tag since that is the one you are using. It doesn't get stripped when I do it.

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the TinyMCE Advanced plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

You can configure it to leave certain tags alone.
it's really useful.

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin (now renamed "Advanced Editor Tools") no longer seems to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when running multi-site and the user was only an admin of the site.  I as super-admin could put whatever html attributes I wanted.  I am sure the long term solution is not to raise their privileges, but it could be a place to start trouble shooting.

@jochem, I have gone down the route of making the tinymce changes, but that does not seem effect editing source.

If anyone has found a better solution, it would be helpful if it was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you stay in the HTML mode in the text editor. Sometimes going back in and making changes in the Visual mode can overwrite HTML elements.

Comment: for sure I am in HTM mode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's Kses that remove it.

Try this

```
function allow_dl_class_content() {
   global $allowedposttags, $allowedtags;
   $newattribute = "class";

   $allowedposttags["dl"][$newattribute] = true;
   $allowedtags["dl"][$newattribute] = true;
}
add_action( 'init', 'allow_dl_class_content' );
```